# What is "the threshold" when mitigating falling damage?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

The 2nd dot of the **Parkour** Merit says

> Cat Leap (••): Your character falls with outstanding grace.
>   When using a Dexterity + Athletics roll to mitigate damage
>   from falling, your character gains one automatic success.
>   Additionally, add your Parkour rating to the threshold of
>   damage that can be removed through this roll. Parkour will
>   not mitigate damage from a terminal velocity fall.

But the section on falling damage (p97) doesn't say anything about a *"threshold of damage that can be removed"*:

> If the character has the opportunity to slow his fall, for
>   example by grabbing an awning, or to soften it, such as by
>   twisting to land on soil rather than concrete, his player may
>   make a Dexterity + Athletics roll, with each success on the roll
>   reducing the damage the character takes by one point. It’s typi­cally not possible to slow or soften a fall at terminal velocity.

So what is it referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Parkour Merit is effectively unchanged from when it was written for *The God-Machine Chronicle* rules update, with the exception that in GMC it explicitly referenced 1e falling rules:

> Cat Leap (••): Your character falls with outstanding
>   grace. When using a Dexterity + Athletics roll to mitigate
>   damage from falling (see the World of Darkness Rulebook,
>   p. 179), your character gains one automatic success. Addition­ally, add your Parkour rating to the threshold of damage that
>   can be removed through this roll. Parkour will not mitigate
>   damage from a terminal velocity fall.

On the referenced page in the nWoD 1e core book, it allows there 'may' be a maximum amount of damage mitigated, presumably arbitrarily determined by the ST:

> The Storyteller may allow your character to try to
>   break his fall by some means, perhaps by grabbing for aw­nings or twisting to strike soil rather than concrete. A
>   single Dexterity + Athletics roll may be called for, with
>   each success gained diminishing damage taken. There may
>   be a limit to how much damage can be shaved, though —
>   say, three. There’s only so much that desperate flailing
>   and grabbing can do when someone falls from a signifi­cant height. Efforts to slow one’s fall are usually useless at
>   terminal velocity.

That rule letting STs set a maximum amount of successes on the roll just doesn't exist in 2e, so the sentence no longer makes sense, and now the sole benefit of **Cat Leap**, in RAW, is the single automatic success.